# What does it mean if someone says "this man I think u are up to something"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

> this man I think u are up to something

One of my friends asked me this question because he got this [text from his girlfriend](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/439556/what-does-it-mean-if-someone-says-this-man-i-think-u-are-up-to-something#comment1055006_439556). So, can anyone help me out to understand this phrase?

Comment: "This man" and "u" don't really go well together in the quote. Is the opening quote misplaced?

Comment: @Lawrence: It seems to be a spoken sentence (colloquial) and I think OP wants to know the meaning of "up to something." Now posted the most likely meaning-in-context as an answer.

Comment: Not missing that entire sentence I quoted

Comment: In the quote, do you take "u" to refer to "this man"?

Comment: Yes Lawrence I think so becoz that is a message typed from my friends girlfriend so he asked me to tell the meaning since I don't know so I posted here

Comment: Ok. Which part(s) are you having trouble with? Also, since the author seems to be available, did you ask her what she meant? If so, what did she say?

Comment: Since I am not the one who is texting her I don't know but please tell me approximately what does that mean

Comment: It doesn’t make any sense as it’s written. It’s ungrammatical. Someone thinks someone is up to something, but there are too many constituents in there for it to make any actual sentence.

Comment: Serious English L & U?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely meaning of "up to something" in context would be

> **Up to something** (idiomatic):
>
> Doing something mischievous or scheming.
>
> [Example] He looks like an angel, but I can tell he's up to something.
>
> Related terms: up to no good

Source: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/up_to_something

Note: It need not necessarily be mischievous or scheming; it can also mean something secret or strange or ***just quiet***, and indicates the speaker would like to know *what it is!* As in,

> Rahul has been very quiet lately... I think he is up to something, but I wonder what?
>
> You have been too well-behaved this week, I think you are up to something.